# Mobile Safari Geolocation API Issues

Tags: geolocation, w3c, mobile-safari

since Mobile Safari's Geolocation API should be an implementation of the W3C Geolocation API I found some bugs. I was wondering if anybody noticed the same.

1. As specified in the W3C Geolocation
   API  the PositionCallback returns a
   Position object, which contains a
   Coordinates object. In this object
   all attributes are of type double.
   Using
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
   and checking the Position object in
   the successCallback the accuracy
   attribute is always an object, but
   should be a double. The heading
   attribute is always -1 when testing
   in the iPhone simulator, but should
   be null or between 0 and 360.
2. Setting the options parameter for
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
   or
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
   as specified in the W3C Geolocation
   API has no effect. No matter what is
   set as the timeout value, the win
   callback is called every 10 seconds.
   For example setting the timeout=1000
   should immediately call either the
   successCallback or errorCallback.

Thanks

Comment: -1 might mean *false* ... since iPhone simulator has no real GPS device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the cycles right now to verify your tests or your interpretation of the spec, but assuming you're right, go ahead and file bugs!

http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

It's possible that these issues are already known about internally: the API is still in draft form and has been changing substantially so we shouldn't assume that they'll always be up to date.  But I'm sure they'll be happy to have the external report.